# ZSH - wrap all commands with a function

Tags: linux, zsh

I'd like to print the PID of any process I run in my command at the beginning (even if it's not a background process).

I came up with this:

```
fn() {
    eval $1
}
```

Now whenever I run a command, I want it to be processed as

```
fn "actual_command_goes_here"&; wait
```

So that this will trigger a background process (which will print the PID) and then run the actual command. Example:

```
$ fn "sleep 5; date +%s; sleep 5; date +%s; sleep 2"&; wait
[1] 29901
1479143885
1479143890
[1] + 29901 done      fn "..."
```

My question is: is there any way to create a wrapper function for *all* commands in Bash/ZSH? That is, when ever I run `ls`, it should actually run `fn "ls"&; wait`.

Comment: bash and zsh are **entirely** different shells, and POSIX sh (the `sh` tag) is a third. Ask about one or the other, not both (or all three) at once.

Comment: ...particularly for this question -- there's a bash answer, but it won't work in zsh; there's probably also a zsh answer that won't work in bash.

Comment: I use ZSH, so either solution would work for, right? Since ZSH is almost fully backwards compatible?

Comment: I'll change my title to just ZSH (since that's more relevant to me). Sorry for the inconvinience.

Comment: BTW, this code is going to break a lot of functionality. `fn "foo=3"`, for instance, will only modify the variable `foo` in a subshell, not in your parent: Thus, this wrapper will prevent you from being able to perform an assignment. `cd` won't work in it either, nor will anything else intended to change the current shell's state.

Comment: Ow, I didn't think about that...

Basically what I want is the PID of the process that just spawned. Is there a reliable way to do this?

Comment: In bash, I'd use `type` to figure out if what we're running is a shell builtin or an external command, and only perform this indirection in the latter case. (Also, in bash, I'd be performing the relevant magic from a DEBUG trap). But zsh is outside my expertise -- I gave it up well over a decade ago, and did my very best to expunge it and all the bad habits it taught me from mind.

Comment: ...might I ask what your real goal is? If this is a XY problem, there's likely to be a more focused way to address your actual need.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128083/discussion-between-anon1038912-and-charles-duffy).